# У меня проблема с базой данных sqlite (Flask)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Хочу создать файл ".db", но выходит ошибка:
Создавал я через консоль -

**>>> from app import db**

**>>> db.create_all()**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages
\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1033, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages
\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1025, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages
\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 956, in get_engine
    return connector.get_engine()
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages
\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 559, in get_engine
    sa_url = make_url(uri)
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages
\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 229, in make_url
    return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)
  File "C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages
\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 291, in _parse_rfc1738_args
    "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'ServerDat
a.db'
```

Вот сам скрипт:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'ServerData.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    titel = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article %r>' % self.id




@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/admin/login/password')
@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    return render_template("admin.html")


#A8E7FF
#99E89C
#FFF4B5


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Прошу помочь!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы используете невалидный URL в данной строке:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'ServerData.db'
```

URL должен иметь вид:

```
sqlite:///filename.db
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html

Comment: Я использую sqlite. Извините  я не разбираюсь еще, я только начал изучать flask и базы данных.  Я переписал как с видео, только там должно быть так: app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///ServerData.db'

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы делаете это через командную строку, а это надо делать в

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

и обязательно в открытом через `with app.app_context()`

Comment: Добавьте отступ после `if __name__ == '__main__':`